# Urban Airship – iOS production pushes working with Ad Hoc but not the Release build

Tags: ios, push, release, adhoc

First let me say that I know confusing the Development and Production API keys are the most common cause of this sort of error, but I am pretty sure that is not the case here.

I have my iOS app setup to use the production servers keys as I should. When I test my Ad Hoc build with the production servers everything seems to be fine. But on any apps purchased though iTunes my device tokens always come back as “Inactive”.

The Ad Hoc build and the App Store builds are exactly the same, using the same API keys. I am pretty sure that I do not have my Development and Production keys confused.

Where do I go from here?

Answer (score 0):

You should check the keys in your UA account...
If necessary, reupload them.

Comment: I assume by this you mean the Certificate (with the file extension .p12) that you have to upload to the UA site? I will give it a shot.

Comment: Yes, the production and development keys.

Comment: I re-exported my "Production Push SSL Certificate" from the provisioning portal. Used the Keyring to save it as a .p12 file and reuploaded to to Urban Airship. The result was the same.

Answer (score 0):

Check

1. APP_STORE_OR_AD_HOC_BUILD is set to YES in airshipConfig.plist?
2. Check account settings.Production is up and running in UA
3. Make this log as an alert and try and see what the error comes

   -(void)application:(UIApplication *)app didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)err
   {
        UALOG(@"%@",[NSString stringWithFormat: @"Error: %@", err]);

   }

Comment: Honestly my app was written in Titanium Studio using the Urban Airship plugin. According to the plugins documentation APP_STORE_OR_AD_HOC_BUILD is a boolean and requires a TRUE or FALSE value. I have it set to TRUE. I guess this could be the issue if the Documentation is wrong, but then why would the Ad Hoc build still work? And since the Ad Hoc build does work, how could I test it without rebuilding it for the app store and waiting a week for them to review it?